# お世辞にも and quote

Tags: grammar, translation

> セイバーはどこに連れて行ってもいつもの調子だし、時には本気で怒っているのでは、と不安になるほど黙り込む事もあった。
> **お世辞にも楽しんでいた、と説明するのは憚られるぐらいの無反応ぶりに対して、こっちは次こそは次こそはと躍起になる。**
>
> Wherever I took Saber she looks the same as always, sometimes she goes so quiet that she looks anxious and I wonder if she is angry.
> Did she have any fun? The explanation to me asking myself this is that my reaction to her lack of responses to the degree that she looked as if she was hesitating, was to go around shops thinking desperately "This is it".

I am probably wrong since I do not understand that bold sentence. Can someone help me?

Comment: I rewrite the orignal sentences very verbosely . "俺がどこに連れて行っても、セイバーはいつもの調子だった。そして、時にはセイバーは黙り込む事もあった。その沈黙は、「本気で怒っているのではないか？」と、俺が不安になるほどだった。「セイバーは楽しんでいた」と、俺が他の人に説明するのは、お世辞にも憚られるぐらいの無反応ぶりだった。その無反応ぶりに対面して、俺は「次こそは反応を見たい」、「次こそは反応を見たい」と、躍起になった。".

Comment: 1, She doesn't look anxious, but the speaker does. 2, 説明する in this sentence doesn't mean to explain, but to describe. 3, お世辞にも modifies 説明するのは憚られる. 4, 次こそは is an unfinished sentence.

Comment: Thank for rewriting it, I would have never understood it otherwise. One thing I don't get is why in the sentence セイバーはどこに連れて行ってもいつもの調子だし、時には本気で怒っているのでは、と不安になるほど黙り込む事もあった。; Why 不安になるほど黙り込む事もあった  does not mean: I become so anxious that there are times when we fall silent.

Comment: @Splikie I don't quite understand your question. "I become so anxious that there are times when we fall silent." should be 黙り込むこともあるほど不安になる.

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood ほど and how it's used.  
For example:  この本は子もが読めるほどやさしい means: This book is easy to the degree that a child can read it.
Am I wrong? If I am not than the translation of 不安になるほど黙り込む事もあった becomes: I become anxious to the degree that there was silence.  Instead the sentence 黙り込むこともあるほど不安になる. becomes: There is silence to the degree that I become anxious.

Comment: @broccoliforest I re-read ほど and I was mistaken:  AほどB= To the degree of A, do/be/etc... B.---> B so much that reaches A. 不安になるほど黙り込む事もあった= To the extent of becoming anxious, sinking in silence. Such a thing happened.---> So much silence that I become anxious, such a thing happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I take the part in bold letters in such a way as “She doesn’t show any interest in my addressing to her. So I got eager to let her quickly respond to me next time, and another next time.” — sorry for my poor English translation.

お世辞にも楽しんでいた、と説明するのは憚られるぐらい can be translated as “It can by no means suggest that she was enjoying my call / solicitation.

お世辞にも means “even for sake of compliment / lip service” by verbatim translation, and expresses a strong negation, for example;

> 彼女はお世辞にも美人とは言えない。
> She isn’t beautiful by any means.
>
> 彼はお世辞にも絵が上手いとは言えない。
> He is by no means a good painter.
>
> 彼の英語はお世辞にも流暢とは言えない。
> He doesn’t speak English well at all.

You can replace 'お世辞にも' with the similar phrase, '(お)義理にも' meaning 'even under ethical obligation.'

Comment: と説明するのは憚られるぐらい= This is the part I still don't understand. 
お世辞にも=By any standard
楽しんでいた=She was having fun 
と説明するのは=Explaining that
憚られるぐらい=To the degree of being hesitated

I don't understand how that connects the way you did though. Could you show me how the clauses would be divided? For example I believe it's like this [[お世辞にも楽しんでいた]、と説明するのは]憚られるぐらい

Comment: @Splikie You're right. The clauses are like you wrote and it fits Yoichi's answer perfectly :)

Comment: ^ Eh? You parse it as お世辞にも[「楽しんでいた」、と]説明するのは憚られる, no? Cos お世辞にも modifies 説明するのは憚れる, not 楽しんでいた

Comment: Yeah, that's probably more accurate